# What's the best way to 'bundle' a gem inside a Mac app?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, rubygems

I've inherited a small obj-C utility app that acts as a wrapper around a ruby script (which is obviously included as a resource in the application).

The helper ruby script, though, requires the json gem. What's the best way to include the gem (and the gem's dependencies) within the app?

I could have the application run a check when it loads to see if the gem is installed and then gem install it, but I thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: You could always just put the `.gem` file in your app bundle, and use `gem` to install that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to check if the json gem has any dependencies:

```
$ gem dependency json
```

The version I have installed has no dependencies, so then you need to get a copy of the gem into your bundle.

```
$ cd /my/project/resources
$ gem unpack json
```

Then, to require it, you can use the line:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'json-VERSION','lib','json')
```

replacing VERSION with the gem version.